# Minecraft - Executing at player NOT looking down

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've searched everywhere I can, and I currently can't find a way to /execute as a player who is NOT looking down. Is there any way (in 1.13 or 1.14) to test for this?

Comment: Youve researched, which is good, but have you tried to make anything work yourself? Generally, you will solicit better responses if you show commands you have tried which arent working, or can at least give an example of what you plan to do and which part specifically you are stuck on.

Comment: I tried /execute as @a[x_rotation=90] at @s run say test, and that works for half of what I want. What I needed was something that executes at someone who isn't looking down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/execute as @a[x_rotation=-90..80] at @s run
```

That should execute only people who are looking up. (if it doesn't work try rearranging those numbers.)

Comment: Oh, I forgot about "..", I'll rearrange them to everything except for straight down, thanks for the help!